# Shape Error while using SciKit Learn's MinMaxScaler

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, deep-learning

I am getting the following error while trying to load a scaler to make a prediction on a trained neural network: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (317,257) (269,) (317,257)

Some context: the first number (317, 257) is the shape of the data set I am trying to make a prediction on, while (269,) is the shape of the training set. I pickled the scaler and loaded it back in, but will get to that later. Before I apply OneHotEncoder, the data set only has 9 columns. After LabelEconder and OneHotEncoder is applied, it expands to 269 columns (there are a lot of large categorical variables within the data).

My code:

Applying OneHotEncoder after applying LabelEncoder:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_4 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X_4.fit_transform(X[:, 3].astype(str))
labelencoder_X_5 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 4] = labelencoder_X_5.fit_transform(X[:, 4].astype(str))
labelencoder_X_6 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 5] = labelencoder_X_6.fit_transform(X[:, 5].astype(str))
labelencoder_X_7 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 6] = labelencoder_X_7.fit_transform(X[:, 6].astype(str))
labelencoder_X_8 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 7] = labelencoder_X_8.fit_transform(X[:, 7].astype(str))
labelencoder_X_9 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 8] = labelencoder_X_9.fit_transform(X[:, 8].astype(str))

onehotencoder_X = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8])
X = onehotencoder_X.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

Fitting to the scaler during training:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.externals import joblib
sc = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
joblib.dump(sc, 'scaler.pkl') 
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
```

Then retrieving the scaler and attempting to transform test data:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
sc = joblib.load('scaler.pkl') 
dataset = sc.transform(dataset) #Error happens here
```

The test data set is pretty large since it does expand to 257 of 269 of the variables - but ideally I want to be able to predict on just a single row of data. In order to get the correct shape, do I have to append that data to a set that contains ALL of the different categories within the categorical data? What happens if a row of data has a value that was not present in the dataset? This just seems inefficient, so there must be a simple fix to this, right?

Thank you for any help you can provide. If you need any additional details, please let me know.

**Update**: I am pickling all the encoders and loading them back in when trying to encode the test set. I am then using .transform instead of .fit_transform on the test set. I feel like this is a step in the right direction, but here is the error I am getting now: ValueError: y contains new labels: ['0' '1' '2']

Comment: "(317, 257) is the shape of the data set I am trying to make a prediction on, while (269,) is the shape of the training set" You can't use a network trained using 269 features with data with 257 features. You need to use the same encoders on the test data.

Comment: pls do not use the comments space for such updates - edit & update your post instead

Comment: @ncfirth I am using the same encoder. Please see update in post. I am pickling them.

Comment: Your test data contains labels not found in the training set. You'll need to fit the LabelEncoder to the entire set - train concat test.